# Java - Assigning arguments to multiple variables in constructor

Tags: java, variables, constructor, arguments

I've searched online and cannot find an answer.  Is it improper to assign an argument to more than one variable in a constructor or does there have to be a one-to-one relationship?

```
public A6HangmanLogic(String keyPhrase, int numberOfGuesses)
{
    this.keyPhrase = keyPhrase;
    this.numberOfGuesses = numberOfGuesses;
    guessesLeft = numberOfGuesses;
}
```

The value of *guessesLeft* (a static int) is returned from an accessor method updated through a loop.  I can certainly write a mutator method, but then I have to call it.  I could also change *this.numberOfGuesses* to just *guesses* and not have that third variable assignment at all.

Comment: It's fine. However if you find you're getting too much code in your constructor, just create another method and call that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't assign the same value to multiple variables.

Another way to solve the problem though might be to store the number of guesses made and then calculate the number of guesses left.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine, but I would store `guessCount` and use the default initualized value of zero:

```
private guessCount;
```

I would also rename `numberOfGuesses` to `maxGuesses` so it's clearer what it means (it's also more conventional).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to assign an argument to as many variables as you like.

You are allowed to use them in a similar way as you would in a method.